# How to pass input field name as an argument in javascript function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've created a JavaScript function that checks if a certain data already exists in my database. What I want to know is if there is a way to make the input field name in a JavaScript pass as an argument

Here is my code

```
    function checkDataAvailability(displayid,input_id,fieldname)
    {
        'use strict';
        $(document).ready(function(){
            //var x = document.getElementByName(fieldname).elements;
            $(displayid).load('php/signcheck.php').show();
            $(input_id).keyup(function(){
                 },
                $.post('php/signcheck.php', { username: form.x.value }, 
              //$.post('php/signcheck.php', { username: form.fieldName.value }, 
                function(result){
                    $(displayid).html(result).show();
                });
            });

        });
    }
    var a =  checkDataAvailability ('#userstat','#username_input','username');
```

A little explanation. The two commented lines are the two methods I've tried to run the field name as an argument separately. Unfortunately they aren't working.

Here is my form

```
<form action="php/register_exec.php" method="POST" name="form">
Username <span id="userstat" class="checkerr"></span>
<input type="text" name="username" id="username_input" required>
</form>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById('username_input').value`

Comment: you can pass it as `var a =  checkDataAvailability ('userstat','username_input','username');`

Answer (score 1):

Passing form fieldnames as argument is no different than passing string argument to functions

```
var a = checkDataAvailability ('userstat','username_input','username');
```

Important thing is what you do inside the function.

You can get the value of input field in primarily two ways

1. Directly read the value using value property as:

   ```
   document.getElementById('username_input').value
   ```

   or

   ```
   document.getElementById(fieldid).value //if you pass fieldid to your function
   ```
2. Use the form field directly

   ```
   //assuming you pass formname and fieldname as variables to your function
   var form = document.getElementById(formname);
   var inputvalue = form.elements.namedItems(fieldname).value
   ```

You can modify them to suit your jquery syntax if need be.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already using the [jQuery](http://jquery.com) library, you can continue using it.

```
$('input[name="' + fieldname + '"]').val()
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 ways of achieving what you desire -

- If you want to stick with your current code pattern, then replacing form.fieldname with form[fieldname] would get you the correct results. This is because fieldname is a string, and form."some string" would give you an error.
- The other two ways are the same as neouser99 and avck specified in their answers.